# node.js and command line (cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd

I'm looking for solution or NPM for calling Windows command line from node.js application.

What I want is call some batch files and run them on machine with node.js, of course with parameters and also read their output.

Comment: Are you looking for http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) library is extremely portable and will achieve what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard module [child_process.spawn()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for this.

From the documentation example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Replace `'ls'` with `'c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe'`, and `['-lh', '/usr']` with `['/c', 'batfile.bat']` to run the batch file `batfile.bat`.

Comment: For portability, it's better to replace `'ls'` with `process.env.comspec`. Also, `child_process.exec` might be easier to use than `spawn` if you don't need to process the batch file's output until it's complete.